# Does anyone know how to make a magnifying glass that appears while the user is dragging in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[This is how it works right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44h0L.gif)

I want the magnifying glass to pop up when the user is dragging, and show a zoomed in view of the photo to help the user drag the line to the right spot.  I can't get the X and Y coordinates right, so it just goes wherever.

This is the ZStack that contains the magnifying glass...

```
ZStack{
                    Image("demo")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .cornerRadius(50)
                    .frame(width: 500, height: 500, alignment: .center)
                    .position(x: CGFloat(self.magnifyX), y: CGFloat(self.magnifyY))

                }
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(
                    ZStack{
                        Circle().fill(Color.black).frame(width: 5, height: 5, alignment: .center)
                        Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 4)
                    }

              )
                .position(x: CGFloat(self.magnifyX), y: CGFloat(self.magnifyY-75))
```

I'd be open to other ways of doing it as well, if this is not the correct way to do it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I can't comment yet... Are you able to share your code for `magnifyX` and `magnifyY`?

Looking at the screen capture you shared, the magnification seems to be following the line, it's obviously just higher, but it's also the opposite of/mirroring your movements, i.e. as you move left to right, it's moving right to left.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your suggestion. I set magnifyX and magnifyY to be negative, so now it moves in the right direction, but it's still too high and too far to the right. 

Here is the code for the magnifyX and magnifyY values... They are the XY coordinates from the drag gesture... https://imgur.com/a/BAiiZWl

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code below, the only thing I am still unable to fix/implement is to prevent the [image moving off-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkYoc.jpg):

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentDetailPhoto : View {

    //Properties
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1.0
    @State var touchScale: CGFloat = 2
    @State var isTouchingScreen = false
    @State var isZoomedIn = false
    @State var pointTouchedOnScreen: CGPoint = CGPoint.zero
    @State var panSize: CGSize = CGSize.zero
    @State var fingerState: String = "Finger is not touching the image"
    @State var prevSize: CGSize = CGSize.zero

    //@State var counter  = 0
    @State var touching = false
    @State var xPos = 0
    @State var yPos = 0

    //let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var cakeName: String

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Image("\(self.cakeName)")
                .grayscale(0.999)
                .opacity(0.5)

            GeometryReader { reader in

                Image("\(self.cakeName)")
                    .resizable()
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .offset(x: self.panSize.width, y: self.panSize.height)
                    .scaleEffect(self.isTouchingScreen ? self.touchScale : 1, anchor: UnitPoint(x: self.pointTouchedOnScreen.x / reader.frame(in: .global).maxX, y: self.pointTouchedOnScreen.y / reader.frame(in: .global).maxY))
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: self.isZoomedIn ? .fill : .fit)
                    .frame(maxWidth: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 10, maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.7, alignment: .center)
                    .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)

                        .onChanged {  (value) in

                            self.fingerState = "Finger is touching the image" // for debug purpose only

                            self.isZoomedIn = true

                            self.isTouchingScreen = true

                            self.pointTouchedOnScreen = value.startLocation

                            self.scale = self.touchScale

                            self.panSize = CGSize(width: (value.translation.width * self.touchScale/2), height: (value.translation.height * self.touchScale/2))
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in

                        self.fingerState = "Finger is not touching the image" // for debug purpose only

                        self.isZoomedIn = false

                        self.isTouchingScreen = false

                        self.panSize = CGSize.zero

                        self.prevSize = CGSize.zero
                    })
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1))
                    //.offset(x: 0, y: -50)
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

            //             Add a watermark on top of all the layers
            //            Image("logo_small")
            //                .resizable()
            //                .scaledToFit()
            //                .opacity(0.05)
            //                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 10, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 10,  alignment: .center)
            //                .clipShape(Circle())

        }
    }
}


#if DEBUG
struct MapView01_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        Group {

            // iPhone SE
            ContentDetailPhoto(cakeName: "cake_0000")
            .previewDevice("iPhone SE")


            // iPhone X
            ContentDetailPhoto(cakeName: "cake_0000")
            .previewDevice("iPhone X")

        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're SwiftUI in an iPhone app, using the iOS simulator. The simulator *simulates* touches. There is no actual API on the iPhone that supports that because you're finger can't magically turn into a magnifying glass (there is no other pointer input).

macOS and iPadOS is a bit of a different story. On macOS you could use the [Hover API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/hovereffect) to natively change the pointer using NSCursor, or make use of the new [UIPointerInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipointerinteraction?language=objc) on iPadOS.

Comment: It works the same on my iPhone. I created an Overlay that acts as a magnifying glass. The only thing is I can’t get the X,Y coordinates right.